# How can I change JRE version in Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I have an project in Eclipse and I need change my JRE version in this progect to JRE 1.7 from JRE 1.8. 
 How can I do it?

Comment: See http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-assign_default_jre.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Preferences go to 'Java > Installed JREs' and add the Java 8 JRE/JDK if it is not already there.

In the Properties for the project look at 'Java Build Path'. On the 'Libraries' tab edit the JRE entry and select Java 8.

You may also want to set the Java Compiler preferences for the project (or the global preferences) to specify Java 8 compliance.

Note: You need to be running Eclipse Luna (4.4) or later for full Java 8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs